# How to properly use verifyNoUnwantedInteractions() in Python Mockito?

Tags: python, mockito

I tried using `verifyNoUnwantedInteractions()` in the Python version of Mockito, but either I have an incorrect understanding of what it should do or it does not really work. What I thought would happen was that it would check that there were no un`expect`ed interactions with the stubbed methods. However, here's what happens:

This passes. I would expect that the destroy() call would raise an exception because it was not `expect`ed

```
expect(maker, times=1).create().thenReturn(thing)
when(maker).destroy().thenReturn(thing)
maker.start() # Calls both create() and destroy()
verifyNoUnwantedInteractions(maker)
```

This does not pass because destroy() was called more than zero times. `verifyNoUnwantedInteractions()` is not necessary as it fails anyway.

```
expect(maker, times=1).create().thenReturn(thing)
expect(maker, times=0).destroy().thenReturn(thing)
when(maker).destroy().thenReturn(thing)
maker.start() # Calls both create() and destroy()
verifyNoUnwantedInteractions(maker)
```

So far it seems to me that `verifyNoUnwantedInteractions()` is pretty useless, what is the reason to use it and how to do it properly?

Comment: I got squared eyes now, but ... both code examples you posted are identical.

Comment: @herr.kaste Nice catch, I forgot to edit the second example when posting the question. Thanks for letting me know. BTW the question is still open if you happen to have a clue ;-)

Answer (score 2):

`verifyNoUnwantedInteractions` only checks `expect`ed stubs. Stubs you create via `when` are left out.

Now I think this comes down to what is the difference between `when` and `expect`. If you do

```
when(maker).destroy()
```

you can call it as often as you want including zero times. You can but surely don't have to `verify` how many times you called it after running the unit under test. This will like any other assertion throw in the test function, namely when you *verify*.

Compare that to `expect` where you setup a call time expectation upfront.

```
expect(maker, times=1).destroy()
```

Now your code under test can call that method exactly once otherwise it will throw in the code under test.

For what we discussed here in the examples, `verifyNoUnwantedInteractions` will only check if `maker.destroy()` has been called *at all*.

Comment: I hope I finally understand, so I can use `verifyNoUnwantedInteractions()` to check that the `destroy()` method was executed the expected number of times and not less? Because I do not see any other use case. I also think the name is quite misleading, I thought that it would check that all interactions with the object were `expect()`ed, but it seems that it should be called something like `verifyExpectedInteractionsHappened()`